# Вывод элементов в RecyclerView из центра

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Такая проблема необходимо выводить элементы в RecyclerView, количество возможных элементов от 1 до 9, как сделать что бы данные элементы выводились из центра RecyclerView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код создания RecyclerView и создание адаптера:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cards_users"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/game_map"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_menu">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


    gameUserClass=deserializeGameCardsList(server_answer);
    cardsUser=findViewById(R.id.cards_users);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(GameActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    cardsUser.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
    cardsPlayerAdapter= new CardsPlayerAdapter(gameUserClass.getFirstPlayer());
    cardsUser.setAdapter(cardsPlayerAdapter);
```

Comment: Видимо вам нужно [писать свой LayoutManager](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/true_engineering/blog/267497/) под это дело. Или попытаться найти готовый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не очень хорошо понимаю, что конкретно вам необходимо. Но есть 2 варианта, простой (но который может вам не помочь) и сложный.

Простой заключается в том, чтоб расположить ваш `RecyclerView` в центре экрана и сделать ему размер `wrap_content` и тогда при появлении 1-го элемента он появится в середине, при появлении второго `RecylerView` расширится и оба элемента тоже будут посередине. Я не уверен, что именно это поведение вам необходимо, но можете попробовать.

Сложный это писать свой `LayoutManager`. Это задача вообще нетривиальная, но зато тут вы можете сделать именно то поведение которое вам необходимо. Можете посмотреть как это делать вот [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/true_engineering/blog/267497/) и [тут](https://medium.com/android-development-by-danylo/10-steps-to-create-a-custom-layoutmanager-2f30ab2f979d).

И да пребудет с вами сила если вы решите пойти сложным путем=)))

Comment: Andrew спасибо за правки=)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, сработал первый способ, просто ширину сделал wrap_content, как же я сам об этом не догадался